# How to filter a many2many field in odoo8?

Tags: odoo

I've the following model, and the extend to the product_template

```
class Version(models.Model):
    _name='product_cars_application.version'

    name = fields.Char()
    model_id = fields.Many2one('product_cars_application.model',string="Model")
    brand_id = fields.Char(related='model_id.brand_id.name',store=True,readonly=1)
    year_id = fields.Char(related='model_id.year_id.name',store=True,readonly=1)

from openerp.osv import osv,fields as Fields

class product_template(osv.osv):
    _name = 'product.template'
    _inherit = _name
    _columns = {
        'versions_ids':Fields.many2many('product_cars_application.version',string='Versions')
    }
```

And the following controller which I need to filter products by version_id

```
@http.route('/pa/get_products/<version_id>', auth='none', type='json',website=True)
    def get_products(self,version_id,**kwargs):
        #TODO APPEND SECURITY
        version_id = int(version_id)
        products = http.request.env['product.template'].sudo().search([(version_id,'in','versions_ids')])
```

I get none products in return while the version_id is in versions_ids.
Do anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to make the value of comparison of the field a list, maybe becouse the field versions_ids is a many2many

I have solved like this:

```
@http.route('/pa/get_products/<version_id>', auth='none', type='json',website=True)
def get_products(self,version_id,**kwargs):
    #TODO APPEND SECURITY
    products = http.request.env['product.template'].sudo().search([('versions_ids','in',[version_id])])
    list = []
    for p in products:
        list.append([p.id, p.name])
    return {
        'products':list,
    }
```

Comment: [('versions_ids.id','=',version_id)] would do it, too.

Comment: CZoellner with field.id doesn't work, only with the value as a list.

Answer (score 0):

"**return products.ids**" is missing   inside `get_products` like:

```
@http.route('/pa/get_products/<version_id>', auth='none', type='json',website=True)
    def get_products(self,version_id,**kwargs):
        #TODO APPEND SECURITY
        version_id = int(version_id)
        products = http.request.env['product.template'].sudo().search([(version_id,'in','versions_ids')])
    return products.ids
```

Comment: I need to return a dict, becouse is a json view.
I solved using:
       products = http.request.env['product.template'].sudo().search([('versions_ids','in',[version_id])])
        list = []
        for p in products:
            list.append([p.id, p.name])
        return {
                'products':list,
                } 
I need to make version_id a list like [version_id]